# Order of messages in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

How exactly does setting `enable.idempotence=true` with `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection > 1` (and less than 5) help in maintaining message ordering?

Each message gets a PID and sequence number to uniquely identify the message.
When a broker receives a message with same PID and sequence - it will reject the message and this solves the duplication issue.

But how does idempotent producer helps with message ordering?
In case message1 succeeds, message 2 fails and message 3 succeeds; that will result in message being retried again and in case it succeeds - the order gets disturbed.

Comment: Messages are sent in batches, not one at a time. Therefore, "message 2 failing (of 3 total in a batch)" is not possible. The batch is ordered.

Comment: Okay, in that case, lets say batch 1 is written successfully, batch 2 fails, then batch 3 succeeds and then batch 2 is written and is success. Doesnt this disturb the order of the message still?

Comment: Not really? Because multiple batches aren't being sent by one producer at a time. The order of the messages **within  a single batch** is all that "ordering" refers to in the documentation

Comment: I don’t quite agree that it means within a single batch. Why would be need an idempotent producer to maintain order within a batch. Order within a batch is anyway not going to be disturbed with retries.

Comment: Honestly, even without idempotent producer, I've never ran into a scenario where records get out of order from when `send()` was called by a producer, so I don't really know. And even if they might have been out of order, when we used Kafka Streams, that was all re-ordered transparently, I guess